# Java: Variable is not incrementing

Tags: java, methods, static

I have three classes: Movement, Collision and Variables(The Variables class is where I store my variables and all of them are public and static. Considering I am new to java I don't really understand what the static keyword does, so my problem might be with the static keyword.). In my Collision class there is a method which checks for collision within the map. Now this method works perfectly:

```
public void checkCollision(int x, int y)
 {

    if (x == 100){
        Variables.collisionRight = true;

    } else {
        Variables.collisionRight = false;
    }
 }
```

Here I have a method in my Movement class which does not work:

```
public void playerMovement (int x, int y)
{
    if (RightKeyPressed == true & collisionRight == false) {
        x += Variables.speed;

    }
}
```

Here is how i call these methods:

```
someObject.checkCollision(Variables.playerX, Variables.playerY);
someOtherObject.playerMovement(Variables.playerX, Variables.playerY);
```

Seems to me the problem is that this line:

```
x += Variables.speed;
```

If i change

```
x
```

to

```
Variables.playerX
```

Everything works fine, but that's not how I want it to work.

It's not working. Which basically should be (Variables.playerX += Variables.speed)
All the methods are samples.

I want to know why is my x (Variables.playerX) variable not incrementing by 3(which is my Variables.speed variable);

Comment: Your title is not useful. It should describe the specific problem.

Comment: just saying use  (RightKeyPressed  & !collisionRight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that `Variables.playerX` is getting passed *by value* as `x`. When the function modifies `x`, it is effectively modifying a local copy of `Variables.playerX`.

For further discussion, see [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) and [Java is Pass-by-Value, Dammit!](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

One way to address this is by passing (a reference to) the `Variables` object instead of `x` and `y`:

```
public void playerMovement (Variables vars)
{
    if (RightKeyPressed && !collisionRight) {
        vars.x += vars.speed;
    }
}
```

P.S. Note how I rewrote the `if` condition. While what you have is not incorrect, idiomatically we don't explicitly compare booleans against `true` and `false`. Also, `&&` and `||` are preferred over `&` and `|` in boolean contexts because they [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: So how do I make a method in that class that changes the value of my `Variables.playerX` variable?

Comment: @GeorgiTonchev: By passing a reference. See the updated answer.